# "Explain a complex process" with snagit

Tags: photoshop, snapshot

Often I have a situation when I meed to show whole picture but clarify details

I would like to create something like this:

[image: Explain a complex process]
<sub>(source: [techsmith.com](http://www.techsmith.com/snagit/assets/img/10/default/mag-customerdocs.jpg))</sub>

As I am not a designer and not familiar with PhotoShop I would like to use some tool.

Does anyone know how to do it with **snagit**?

Or advice some other tool that can create something like that.

Comment: Great question and answer, but I think they belong on SuperUser. The "complex process" of the title could be anything, not necessarily programming related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snagit (version 7, 8, 9, 10) has a feature called 'Spotlight and Magnify' that you could use to create a look similar to the pic you posted. You can bring out a specific area of the image by increasing the size of the area, or by dimming/blurring the non selected area. After you take your capture and are in editing mode, you can apply the effect. Here is a tutorial - http://www.techsmith.com/learn/snagit/9/edit/image-effects.asp#8

Also, Snagit has lots of arrows, shapes and drawing tools you can apply to your image. Feel free to visit our website for lots of tutorials.